# I am having trouble defining a function is a bijection. The question is as follows:

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Define $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ by $f(x,y)=(x-y, x+y)$.  Show that $f$ is a bijection.

I understand how to prove that it is one to one but I am having trouble finding the range in order to prove an ordered pair such as $(p,q) \in \operatorname{range}(f)$.

Comment: To show it is a bijection you need to prove it is injective and surjective.  Any thoughts as to either?

Comment: Even simpler: your function is a linear operator defined on a finite dimensional space, so it is injective iff it is surjective.

Comment: Just to improve your terminology: you’re not *defining* but *proving* that the function is a bijection.

Comment: Your suggestions have not gone unnoticed thank you I was able to put my answer together correctly.  You are right @DonAntonio it was easier to prove that the function was surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(u,v) = (x-y,x+y)$.  So do a bit of algebra to write $(x,y)={}$something depending on $u$ and $v.$  Maybe it will help to write it as
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
x & - & y & = & u \\
x & + & y & = & v
\end{array}
$$
and solve for $x$ and $y$.

You can use the result to show that $f$ is both one-to-one and onto.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)  \iff$

$x_1-y_1=x_2-y_2 \;$ and

$\; x_1+y_2=x_2+y_2$

thus by addition and substraction; we get the unique solution.

$2x_1=2x_2\; $ and$\; 2y_1=2y_2$

or

$(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$.  Qed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can simply show that $g(X,Y)=(\frac{X+Y}{2}, \frac{X-Y}{2})$ is the reciprocal function
$g \circ f(x,y)=g(x-y,x+y)=(x,y)$
$f \circ g(x,y)=f(\frac{x+y}{2},\frac{x-y}{2})=(x,y)$

Comment: I think you meant "the inverse function" instead of "reciprocal function".

Answer (score 0):

In order to show bijectivity you have to show both injectivity and surjectivity:

- injectivity: let $f(x,y) =f(x',y')$, then we have the following system: $x-y=x'-y'$ and $x+y = x'+y'$ It's easy to show using gaussian elimination that $(x,y)=(x',y')$
- surjectivity: $\forall (y,y')$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ You want to show that there exists $(x,x') \in \mathbb{R^2}$ such that $f(x,x') = (y,y')$ Notice that $x= (y+y')/2$ and $x'= (y-y')/2$

Comment: You have the injectivity (definition) part backwards...and wrong. It is painfully trivial that $\;x=y\implies F(x)=F(y)\;$ . What **must be proved**, and you didn't do, is precisely the other way around: $$f(x,y)=f(x',y')\implies f(x,y)=f(x',y')\ldots$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Indeed, I edited my post